# Deployment of Python App on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I created my first chatbot with Chatterbot library. Now I want to deploy it through Heroku, but this is impossible.

My chatbot is composed of some files (py, csv, yml, json, txt).
This is the structure:

botusers (csv file)  
Magghy (py file) 
magghybot (py file) 
Procfile  
Requirements (txt file) 
telegramtoken (txt file) 
conversation.yml (in folder named lang) 
math_words.json  (in folder named lang)

I created a "Procfile" (worker: python magghybot.py) and "Requirements.txt"

Then, I create my Heroku Profile and I tried to deploy my project but on terminal I have this problem:

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 5.22 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to magghy.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/magghy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/magghy.git'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you specified the Python runtime? See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I solved this problem :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Python runtime in a `runtime.txt` file. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for more details.